getBoundingClientRect() method returning different top value in different devices
In reactjs, I am displaying a cursor before the current letter in a typing test app. I am using the current letter's absolute positions to position the cursor. It is working, but when used in mobile phone there is slightly smaller value of top position of the letter
const rect = spanRef.current.getBoundingClientRect(); setCurrentCharacterPos({top: rect.top, left: rect.left});
Tried logging the value in both devices and got follwing result -
Mobile: 212.72727966308594
Desktop: 213.09091186523438
Code -
<div onClick={handleContainerClick} ref={containerRef} className={`border leading-[3em] max-h-[10rem] h-[10rem] overflow-hidden ${showTextTransition ? 'opacity-0' : 'opacity-1'} transition duration-100`}>
                {!showTextTransition && (
                    <>
                        {sampleText.split('').map((char, index) => {
                            return <Letter key={index} windowWidth={windowWidth} scrollableDivScrollTop={scrollableDivScrollTop} char={char} index={index} setCurrentCharacterPos={setCurrentCharacterPos} currentIndex={inputText.length} isIncorrect={charactersStatus.length > 0 ? charactersStatus[index] !== null && !charactersStatus[index] : false} />
                        })}

                        {/* simulating an extra line */}
                        <span className="text-4xl whitespace-pre">                                                                                                                                      </span>

                        {
                            (inputText.length < sampleText.length && (currentCharacterPos.left >= 0 && currentCharacterPos.top+4 >= containerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().top)) &&
                            <div className={`bg-light-active dark:bg-dark-active inline-block h-12 w-[2px] absolute transition-all duration-100 ${!startTime ? 'animate-fade' : ''}`} style={{ left: `${currentCharacterPos.left}px`, top: `${currentCharacterPos.top + 3}px` }}></div>
                        }
                    </>
                )}

            </div>

Letter Component -
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"

export default function Letter({ char, index, currentIndex, isIncorrect, setCurrentCharacterPos, scrollableDivScrollTop, windowWidth }) {
    const spanRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(index===currentIndex && spanRef.current){
            const rect = spanRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
            setCurrentCharacterPos({top: rect.top, left: rect.left});
        }
    }, [currentIndex, index, spanRef, scrollableDivScrollTop, windowWidth]);

    return (
        <span className="text-4xl" ref={spanRef}>
            <span className={`transition duration-100 ${isIncorrect ? 'text-light-danger dark:text-dark-danger' : (index < currentIndex ? 'text-light-hover dark:text-dark-hover' : 'text-light-icon dark:text-dark-icon')}`}>{char}</span>
        </span>
    )
}


Yes, different browsers render things differently. Is there a question you want answered?

Thank you for commenting. I think I just fixed it. It  was the text-4xl property of tailwind css which adds line height as well. I was only taking into account the line-height property of the parent div not the <Letter/> component. So I replaced the text-4xl property with text-[2.5rem] and its working.

Again the issue occured again. And also
console.log(scrollableDiv.scrollTop, lineHeight)```
This logging 56 in desktop and 55.7630.... in Mobile browser even the value is rounded, why does it happen?
